# Phonegap button click event

Tags: javascript, cordova

I can't get the button to call my javascript function and I'm starting to run in circles. I'm not very experienced in this area and to me it looks like all the examples I've seen.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>BONJA</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="head">
                <img src="res/logo/institucional.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <form>
                    <input type="button" value="Fazer Login" onclick="login()" class="button" id="loginClick" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event notConnected">N&atilde;o conectado</p>
                <p class="event connecting">conectando</p>
                <p class="event connected">conectado</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function login() {
            //initialize login
            var parentElement = document.getElementByID('deviceready');
            var notConnectedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.notConnected');
            var connectingElement = parentElement.querySelector('.connecting');

            notConnectedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
            connectingElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

            alert("Hello world!");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Im testing everything on the iPhone Simulator by the way.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you share full HTML?

Comment: Small addition, outside the scope of your question, but related to your coding. It is better to seperate javascript from HTML. Check out this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the first line in `login()` with `document.getElementById()` and i have done some code changes in the `login()` with `style` `display` Properties.

Check out comments in code, and you will get an idea

```
 function login() {
     //initialize login
     var parentElement = document.getElementById('deviceready'); // getElementById <- Not ID
     var notConnectedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.notConnected');
     var connectingElement = parentElement.querySelector('.connecting');

     //notConnectedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
     //connectingElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
     notConnectedElement.style.display = 'none'; // Newly Added
     connectingElement.style.display = 'block'; // Newly Added
     alert("Hello world!");
 }
```

[**<kbd>Fiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/p9xe6/2/)

Comment: Thanks for that but it still doesn't do anything :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it works when I put the function call inside the form tag

```
 <form action="javascript:login()">
```